# SelectionFragment class missing - Android based Facebook development

Tags: android, facebook

I've created a project where I want to have a list of friends returned. I'm following [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends/#step2c) and at section 2c I have realized that my build does not contain a SelectionFragment class. Where online could I download this class, or does anyone have the code for this class? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

maybe here [SelectionFragment.java on github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/facebook/scrumptious/SelectionFragment.java)

Comment: Thank you- is this a standard class? I created my own project from scratch, so I thought that Scrumptious edited it for it's own means. Will this file work with something I've made from scratch?

Comment: Have no idea, try yourself ;]

Comment: Did- it doesn't seem to like it at all. It won't allow me to edit files within the folder that I need to put it in. Do you have an idea of a solution to this? This is my first experience developing an android application, I don't have too much knowledge regarding it yet.

Answer (score 0):

My guess this class needed to be created a little bit earlier in tutorial.

Choose "Step 1b" link in right column of a page.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate#step1b

It says like:"Create a new fragment class in your package for the authenticated UI. Name this class ''SelectionFragment'' and make its superclass Fragment."

Comment: Huh, well the thing is, I can already login automatically I believe. It has me login to my facebook app on the device that I'm using, and the application won't work unless I have it logged int.